# winJS ListView dynamic datasource edit issue

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

### winJS ListView issue

I am working on a winJS application.I have listview.I need to add new data to an existing list view.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the listview is bound with a [WinJS.Binding.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx), just add new items to that list and they'll appear inside listview.

Comment: But in my case i loaded a grouped data.I need to add the start of the list

Answer (score 0):

Suggest use WinJS.Binding.List.createSorted() first and createGrouped on the sorted list. if your sort function can ensure that the newly inserted item comes ahead in sort order - it should appear first in the group.

```
_initializeListView: function initializeListView()
    {
        var data = [{ title: 'parle-ggg', brand: 'parle' }, { title: 'parle-gg', brand: 'parle' }, { title: 'parle-g', brand: 'parle' },
            { title: 'maggi-sauce', brand: 'maggi' }, { title: 'maggi-sauce-2', brand: 'maggi' }, { title: 'maggi-sauce-3', brand: 'maggi' }];
        var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(data);
        var sortedList = list.createSorted(function sorter(item1, item2)
        {
            var result;
            if (item1.title < item2.title) 
                result = -1;
            else if (item1.title == item2.title)
                result = 0;
            else
                result = 1;

            return result;
        });
        var groups = sortedList.createGrouped(
            function groupKey(item)
            {
                return item.brand;
            },
            function groupData(item)
            {
                var result = { title: item.brand };
                return result;
            }
            );
        listView.winControl.itemDataSource = groups.dataSource;
        listView.winControl.groupDataSource = groups.groups.dataSource;
        this.sortedList = sortedList;
    },
    _oncmdclick: function oncmdclick(event) // this is event handler where you want to add new item
    {
        this.sortedList.push(newItem);
    },
```

the above code snippet is tries to create a list sorted by title and grouped by brand. on inserting an item later in sortedList - inserted item is placed in the group properly. for example - adding an item by title 'parle-f' will place it first in the parle brand group whereas adding an item by title 'parle-h' will place it last in the parle brand group.

HTH.

Comment: this is for initialize. in some other eventhandler, need to add the item to sorted list. i have tried in test code and saw insert animation on the page for the added item.